# The meaning of "Nothing much seemed to dent this vision of corporate hegemony squeezing out all but the most profitable trash"

Tags: meaning, sentence

I came across this sentence while looking up the meaning of the word [*hegemony*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hegemony):

> Nothing much seemed to dent this vision of corporate hegemony squeezing out all but the most profitable trash.

It doesn't make any sense to me. The second half of the sentence ("squeezing out...") is particularly the part I find incomprehensible. Although each half of the sentence seems to convey a meaning on its own, the sentence as a whole is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is

[squeeze out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/squeeze+out):

> Some employees were squeezed out by the recent budget cuts

[trash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trash)

> Disparaging, often abusive speech about a person or group.

So my take on this is

> Corporate hegemony getting rid of all except the very profitable of who they consider useless

*Squeezing out* can also mean *form or shape by forcing through an opening*

In slang, *to squeeze one out* is to defecate.

If there had not been a "but" in the sentence, it could be translated into

> Corporate hegemony producing/defecating very profitable low quality stuff

It is alas not possible to find the actual quote except as an example of the use of hegemony

Comment: So far so good. But what does it mean when *trash* is appended?

Answer (score 0):

My reading of it would be that "squeezing out" would mean displacing, or forcing out of the marketplace.

The phrase "the most profitable trash" would mean low-quality mass-produced goods, which can be sold more profitably than high-quality ones.